# binary_search() function doesn't work in my function body

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector, binary-search

The question is -

Given a sorted and rotated array A of N distinct elements which is rotated at some point, and given an element K. The task is to find the index of the given element K in the array A.

Input:
The first line of the input contains an integer T, denoting the total number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case consists of three lines. The first line of each test case contains an integer N denoting the size of the given array. The second line of each test case contains N space-separated integers denoting the elements of the array A. The third line of each test case contains an integer K denoting the element to be searched in the array.

Output:
For each test case, print the index (0 based indexing) of the element K in a new line, if K does not exist in the array then print -1.

User Task:
Complete Search() function and return the index of the element K if found in the array. If the element is not present, then return -1.

Expected Time Complexity: O(log N).

Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1).

Constraints:

1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ N ≤ 107
0 ≤ Ai ≤ 108
1 ≤ K ≤ 108

Example:
Input:
3
9
5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3
10
3
3 1 2
1
4
3 5 1 2
6
Output:
5
1
-1

MY SOLUTION FOR THE REQUIRED FUNCTION:-

```
// vec : given vector of elements  
// K : given value whose index we need to find   

int Search(vector<int> vec, int K) 
{
    if(binary_search(vec.begin(),vec.end(), K))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

This is not the logic for the question, but I was aiming for an approach which would first require me to find whether an element is present in the vector.
But here the output for my code when the above mentioned test cases are given is:-
-1
-1
-1
which indicates that the element isn't found in any cases whereas it's actually present in the vector in the first two cases. Where am I going wrong ??

Comment: the vector must be sorted

Comment: @Berto99 Thanks for pointing out. I was missing this small fact.

Comment: don't worry, you just need to choose whether you want to sort the array, or perform a linear search

Comment: I would go with writing a modified binary search function to meet the time complexity and keep the indices intact, cause that's what I have to return in the end. Thanks pal :) @Berto99

Comment: Please review [mre].

Comment: @amlansahoo07 ok fine, i've posted a possible answer, check it out if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the preconditions of `std::binary_search` as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), is that the array where you are searching on, must be sorted, instead you can write your own linear search:

```
template<class Iterator, class ToFind>
bool linear_search(Iterator start, Iterator end, const ToFind& element){
   while(start != end){
      if(*start == element)
          return true;
      std::next(start);
   }
   return false;
}
```

As @Blastfurnace has pointed out, you can use `std::find` which will do this (but probably better)

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, sorry, my fault

Answer (score 0):

Binary search means you have already sorted array.
All of your input arrays aren't sorted